# Formatter for DataLabels of PlotOptionsSeries not working

Tags: charts, vaadin

Since the upgrade from 23.2.8 to 23.3.1 the Formatter for the DataLabels of PlotOptionsSeries is not working anymore.

e.g.

```
PlotOptionsSeries plotOptionsSeries = new PlotOptionsSeries();
plotOptionsSeries.getDataLabels().setEnabled(true);
plotOptionsSeries.getDataLabels().setFormatter("function() {return 'test';}");
```

shows the y value as DataLabel in the chart. Before the update the expected value of 'test' was shown.

I tried in JSFiddle and everything works as expected.

Edit:
Actually it doesn't matter what you pass as parameter for setFormatter, it seems it has no affect at all anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by setting formatter of PlotOptions of Chart configuartion.
e.g.

```
PlotOptionsBar plotOptionsBar = new PlotOptionsBar();
plotOptionsBar.getDataLabels().setFormatter("return 'test';");
chart.getConfiguration().setPlotOptions(plotOptionsBar);
```